# MySQL: Finding Maximum Value for a Column for each location and server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| location | server | datetime         | max_cpu |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| Chicago  | 1      | 2013-05-01 00:00 | 10      |
| Chicago  | 1      | 2013-05-01 01:00 | 15      |
| Chicago  | 1      | 2013-05-01 02:00 | 11      |
| Chicago  | 2      | 2013-05-01 00:00 | 8       |
| Chicago  | 2      | 2013-05-01 01:00 | 12      |
| Chicago  | 2      | 2013-05-01 02:00 | 13      |
| Atlanta  | 1      | 2013-05-01 00:00 | 11      |
| Atlanta  | 1      | 2013-05-01 01:00 | 12      |
| Atlanta  | 1      | 2013-05-01 02:00 | 19      |
| Atlanta  | 2      | 2013-05-01 00:00 | 21      |
| Atlanta  | 2      | 2013-05-01 01:00 | 15      |
| Atlanta  | 2      | 2013-05-01 02:00 | 17      |
```

I need the maximum CPU for each box in each location for a given day, e.g.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| location | server | datetime         | max_cpu |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| Chicago  | 1      | 2013-05-01 01:00 | 15      |
| Chicago  | 2      | 2013-05-01 02:00 | 13      |
| Atlanta  | 1      | 2013-05-01 02:00 | 19      |
| Atlanta  | 2      | 2013-05-01 00:00 | 21      |
```

I know how to do this for a single criteria (e.g. just location) and tried to expand upon that (see below) but it is not giving me the output I need.

```
SELECT a.location, a.server, a.datetime, a.max_cpu 
  FROM mytable as a INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT location, server, max(max_cpu) as max_cpu
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY location, server
  ) 
  AS b ON 
  (
    a.location = b.location
    AND a.server = b.server
    AND a.max_cpu = b.max_cpu
  )
```

Comment: Your query seems correct. What output does it give you?

Comment: The query works -- see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/845e1/2

Comment: You do need a `distinct` to weed out duplicates (if the max CPU is repeated for different times on that server). The question is whether this table is guaranteed not to have more than one day's worth of data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by finding the max cpu and joining back to the original table.

It seems that you want the *time* of the max as well as the amount (this is not clearly stated in the text, but clear in the results):

```
select t.*
from mytable t join
     (select location, server, DATE(datetime) as thedate, MAX(max_cpu) as maxmaxcpu
      from mytable t
      group by location, server, DATE(datetime)
     ) lsd
     on lsd.location = t.location and lsd.server = t.server and
        lsd.thedate = DATE(t.datetime) and lsd.maxmaxcpu = t.max_cpu
```

This calculates the maxcpu on each day and then joins back to get the appropriate row *or rows* in the original data.  If there is more than one record with the max, you'll get all the records.  If you only want one, you can add `group by location, server, day(datetime)` to the query.

Answer (score 1):

This better answers the "for a given day" part of the question. Since you can ignore the time, this avoids that date hacky thing, is a tad simpler, and if multiple times have the same CPU for that server, it doesn't show duplicates:

```
select distinct a.location, a.server, a.datetime, a.max_cpu
from 
  mytable a
  inner join (
    select location, server, max(max_cpu) as max
    from mytable
    where
      datetime >= ? -- start of day
      and datetime < ? -- start of next day
    group by location, server
  ) b on a.location=b.location and a.server=b.server and a.max_cpu as max
where
  a.datetime >= ? -- start of day
  a.and datetime < ? -- start of next day
```

Answer (score 0):

Query (works only if max_cpu is unique per location, server and Date ):

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c3eb/2)**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.max_cpu = (SELECT MAX(t2.max_cpu)
                    FROM Table1 t2
                    WHERE t2.location = t1.location 
                    AND t2.server = t1.server
                    AND DATE(t2.datetime) = DATE(t1.datetime))
```

Result:

```
| LOCATION | SERVER |                   DATETIME | MAX_CPU |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  Chicago |      1 | May, 01 2013 01:00:00+0000 |      15 |
|  Chicago |      2 | May, 01 2013 02:00:00+0000 |      13 |
|  Atlanta |      1 | May, 01 2013 02:00:00+0000 |      19 |
|  Atlanta |      2 | May, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      21 |
```